# Including phonon environment setup in Qt Creator

Tags: qt4, environment

On Windows XP, I ran "configure", and Qt says that I'm configured to use phonon, but I'm not sure how to set up my environment correctly in Qt Creator. According to the [Qt documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/phonon-overview.html#windows), I need to call:

Set DXSDK_DIR=C:\Program Files\Microsoft DirectX SDK (February 2007)

%DXSDK_DIR%\utilities\bin\dx_setenv.cmd

C:\program files\Microsoft Platform SDK\setenv.cmd

How do I do this in the Qt Creator IDE?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand those sets are required if you want to build phonon itself, but if you rely on already build qt that has phonon enabled, those are not required.

However, if it indeed turns out that you need those too, optimal way would be that you first look into those 2 scripts, extract all the environment variables those 2 scripts set and then go to Control Panel->System->Advanced Tab->Environment Variable Button and set the variables there manually.

There's also a tool call setx available somewhere that you can use, check this thread for example: http://forums.techarena.in/windows-xp-support/1152405.htm